# Sign extension, addition and subtraction binary in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, sign-extension

How would I go about implementing a sign extend from 16 bits to 32 bits in C code?
I am supposed to be using bitwise operators. I also need to add and subtract; can anyone point me in the right direction? I did the first 4 but am confused on the rest. I have to incorporate a `for` loop somewhere as well for 1 of the cases.

I am not allowed to use any arithmetic operators (`+`, `-`, `/`, `*`) and no `if` statements.

Here is the code for the switch statement I am currently editing:

```
unsigned int csc333ALU(const unsigned int opcode,
               const unsigned int argument1,
               const unsigned int argument2) {
unsigned int result;

switch(opcode) {
  case(0x01): // result = NOT argument1
    result = ~(argument1);
    break;
  case(0x02): // result = argument 1 OR argument 2
    result = argument1 | argument2;
    break;
  case(0x03): // result = argument 1 AND argument 2
    result = argument1 & argument2;
    break;
  case(0x04): // result = argument 1 XOR argument 2
    result = argument1 ^ argument2;
    break;
  case(0x05): // result = 16 bit argument 1 sign extended to 32 bits
    result = 0x00000000;
    break;
  case(0x06): // result = argument1 + argument2
    result = 0x00000000;
    break;
  case(0x07): // result = -argument1. In two's complement, negate and add 1.
    result = 0x00000000;
    break;
  default:
    printf("Invalid opcode: %X\n", opcode);
    result = 0xFFFFFFFF;
  }
```

Comment: The easiest way of getting something correct is not to think of your numeric type as representing a number, but instead think of them as being an array of bits, and just do something obvious with the array rather than something clever.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `x ? y : z;` ternary operator?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i believe so

Answer (score 1):

partial answer for sign extension:

```
result = (argument1 & 0x8000) == 0x8000 ? 0xFFFF0000 | argument1 : argument1;
```

Comment: it doesnt extend the FFFF just results in 0x00008000

Comment: sorry, modified answer: == has higher precedence than &

Answer (score 1):

To sign-extend a 16 bit number to 32 bit, you need to copy bit 15 to the upper bits. The naive way to do this is with 16 instructions, copying bit 15 to bit 16, then 17, then 18, and so on. But you can do it more efficiently by using previously copied bits and doubling the number of bits you've copied each time like this:

```
unsigned int ext = (argument1 & 0x8000U) << 1;
ext |= ext << 1;
ext |= ext << 2;
ext |= ext << 4;
ext |= ext << 8;
result = (argument1 & 0xffffU) | ext;
```

To add two 32 bit numbers "manually" then you can simply do it bit by bit.

```
unsigned carry = 0;
result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    // Extract the ith bit from argument1 and argument 2.
    unsigned a1 = (argument1 >> i) & 1;
    unsigned a2 = (argument2 >> i) & 1;
    // The ith bit of result is set if 1 or 3 of a1, a2, carry is set.
    unsigned v = a1 ^ a2 ^ carry;
    result |= v << i;
    // The new carry is 1 if at least two of a1, a2, carry is set.
    carry = (a1 & a2) | (a1 & carry) | (a2 & carry);
}
```

Subtraction works with almost exactly the same code: `a - b` is the same as `a + (~b+1)` in two's complement arithmetic. Because you aren't allowed to simply add 1, you can achieve the same by initialising `carry` to `1` instead of `0`.

```
unsigned carry = 1;
result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    unsigned a1 = (argument1 >> i) & 1;
    unsigned a2 = (~argument2 >> i) & 1;
    unsigned v = a1 ^ a2 ^ carry;
    result |= v << i;
    carry = (a1 & a2) | (a1 & carry) | (a2 & carry);
}
```

To find two's complement without doing the negation, similar ideas apply. Bitwise negate and then add `1`. Adding `1` is simpler than adding `argument2`, so the code is correspondingly simpler.

```
result = ~argument1;
unsigned carry = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 32 && carry; i++) {
    carry &= (result >> i);
    result |= (1 << i);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get sign extension from `short int` to `int`....

```
short int iShort = value;

int i = iShort;  // compiler automatically creates code that performs sign extension
```

Note: going from `i` to iShort will generate a compiler waring.

however, for other situations...

no need to make comparison, the `&` will result in a single bit being either 0 or 1 and be sure to cast the parts of the calculation as int

```
int i = (short int argument&0x8000)? (int)(0xFFFF000 | (int)argument) : (int)argument;
```